# Converter consulta Linq para Dapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, expressões-lambda

Em minha aplicação em possuo a seguinte consulta:

```
public IEnumerable<Cliente> BuscarClientePorAnoETipo(string ano, string filial, string tipoPrestacao)
{
     var filialConvertInt = Convert.ToInt32(filial);
     var prestacaoConvertInt = Convert.ToInt32(tipoPrestacao);

     return Find(x =>  x.AnoVigencia == ano && x.FilialId == filialConvertInt
                && x.TipoPrestacaoId == prestacaoConvertInt&& x.Ativo).ToList();
}
```

Ela funciona normalmente, e me retorna os dados que necessito. Porém, por questões de performance eu estou modificando meus `selects`, utilizando  [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) em todas as minhas consultas.

Por não conhecer a ferramenta muito bem, estou com problemas para converter a consulta para o `Dapper`.
Utilizando como base o que li em alguns artigos, cheguei a esta consulta:

```
public IEnumerable<Cliente> BuscarClientePorAnoETipo(string ano, string filial, string tipoPrestacao)
{
    var filialConvertInt = Convert.ToInt32(filial);
    var prestacaoConvertInt = Convert.ToInt32(tipoPrestacao);

    const string sql = @"select * from clientes c inner join TipoPrestacao t on (c.TipoPrestacaoId = t.TipoPrestacaoId)" +
                        "inner join VencimentoPrestacoes v on (v.VencimentoPrestacaoId = t.VencimentoPrestacaoId)" +
                        "where c.AnoVigencia = @anoVigencia and" +
                        "c.FilialId = @filialId and" +
                        "c.TipoPrestacaoId = @prestacaoId" +
                        "and Ativo = 1";

    using (var cn = Connection)
    {
        cn.Open();

        var clientes = cn.Query<Cliente, TipoPrestacao, VencimentoPrestacao, Cliente>(sql, (c, t, v) =>
        {
            c.TipoPrestacao = t;
            c.TipoPrestacao.VencimentoPrestacao = v;
            return c;
        }, new{anoVigencia = ano, FilialId = filialConvertInt, prestacaoId = prestacaoConvertInt}, splitOn:"ClienteId");

        return clientes.ToList();
    }
}
```

Porém, ao executar, me retorna o seguinte erro:

Detalhes da Exceção:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'andc'.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 32:                 cn.Open();
>
> Linha 33:
>
> Linha 34:                 var clientes = cn.Query(sql, (c, t, v) =>
>
> Linha 35:                 {
>
> Linha 36:                     c.TipoPrestacao = t;

Creio que seja erro de `syntax`, porém não encontrei nada que possa me ajudar.
Ao executar esse código no `SQL Server`, ele me retorna os valores corretos.

Minhas entidades estão da seguinte forma:

### Cliente

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string Orgao { get; set; }
    public string NomeEntidade { get; set; }
    public string Responsavel { get; set; }
    public string Telefone { get; set; }
    public string TipoPendencia { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public string AnoVigencia { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    public int EstadoId { get; set; }
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }
    public int TipoPrestacaoId { get; set; }
    public int FilialId { get; set; }
    public int EnvioPrestacaoId { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoPrestacao TipoPrestacao { get; set; }
    public virtual Filial Filial { get; set; }
    public virtual EnvioPrestacao EnvioPrestacao { get; set; }
}
```

### TipoPrestacao

```
public class TipoPrestacao
{
    public int TipoPrestacaoId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string TipoVencimento { get; set; }
    public string ResponsavelTCE { get; set; }
    public string ContatoTCE { get; set; }
    public int? QuantidadeArquivos { get; set; }

    public int VencimentoPrestacaoId { get; set; }

    public virtual VencimentoPrestacao VencimentoPrestacao { get; set; }
}
```

### VencimentoPrestacao

```
public class VencimentoPrestacao
{
    public int VencimentoPrestacaoId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataJaneiro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataFevereiro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataMarco { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAbril { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataMaio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataJunho { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataJulho { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataAgosto { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataSetembro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataOutubro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNovembro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataDezembro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataTreze { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataQuatorze { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É um problema simples de espaçamento. Se for usar concatenação de `String`, procure colocar sempre um espaço entre as sentenças `and`. Este pedaço:

```
"where c.AnoVigencia = @anoVigencia and" +
"c.FilialId = @filialId and" +
"c.TipoPrestacaoId = @prestacaoId" +
"and Ativo = 1";
```

Pode ser alterado para:

```
" where c.AnoVigencia = @anoVigencia and " +
" c.FilialId = @filialId and " +
" c.TipoPrestacaoId = @prestacaoId " +
" and Ativo = 1 ";
```

Answer (score 2):

O único problema que vejo em seu código, é separação do código por  `+` .
Tente colocar dentro de um único  `"seletc"`. E no [SplitOn](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/399db17e5aa6f1eefaf8fdccff827020be8e6cbb), coloque as chaves de suas entidades.
Ficaria assim o seu código:

```
public IEnumerable<Cliente> BuscarClientePorAnoETipo(string ano, string filial, string tipoPrestacao)
        {

            var filialConvertInt = Convert.ToInt32(filial);
            var prestacaoConvertInt = Convert.ToInt32(tipoPrestacao);

            const string sql =
                @"select * from clientes c inner join TipoPrestacao t on (c.TipoPrestacaoId = t.TipoPrestacaoId)  
                inner join VencimentoPrestacoes v on (v.VencimentoPrestacaoId = t.VencimentoPrestacaoId)
                where c.AnoVigencia = @anoVigencia and c.FilialId = @filialId and c.TipoPrestacaoId = @prestacaoId and c.Ativo = 1";

            using (var cn = Connection)
            {
                cn.Open();

                var clientes = cn.Query<Cliente, TipoPrestacao, VencimentoPrestacao, Cliente>(sql, (c, t, v) =>
                {
                    c.TipoPrestacao = t;
                    c.TipoPrestacao.VencimentoPrestacao = v;
                    return c;
                }, new{anoVigencia = ano, FilialId = filialConvertInt, prestacaoId = prestacaoConvertInt}, splitOn: "ClienteId, TipoPrestacaoId, VencimentoPrestacaoId");
                            return clientes.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Qualquer eventuais dúvidas, a [documentação do Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) possui muitos exemplos de utilização.